# Strange behaviour on merging code-coverage of laravel-code tested by browser-kit-testing

Tags: laravel, merge, phpunit, code-coverage, pcov

Hi crowd intelligence!

I have different testsuites that are processed parallel in teamcity with .cov-files as artifacts  and one build-configuration that does a merge of the code-coverage.

The strange thing is:
code that is tested with the browser-kit-testing methods of laravel in such a way

```
$this->visitRoute('route.name', ['any'=>'params']);
$this->see('any text');
$this->seeElement('#myContainer');
```

will be correctly shown in code-coverage of the testsuite itself

[only real lines of code are marked as covered - curly brackets are white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptktg.png)

but after merging the code-coverage with the other results, these codes won't be completely covered anymore because the curly brackets and other structure-code are marked as not executed

[after merge structure-code like curly brackets that should not count in code-coverage is marked red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8owik.png)

our setup:

- running phpunit 9
- with php7.4
- and laravel 6.x
- in docker-containers
- with alpine-based custom-image
- code-coverage via pcov (it is much faster than xdebug)
- in the beginning it worked very fine in this constellation
- maybe any updates in pcov / phpunit / laravel / browser-kit-testing caused this problem?!
- but we have no idea why it works in single coverage-output but not in merged
- merging via phpcov
- also tried nimut/phpunit-merger - same results
- other code (e.g. some service-classes) that was tested with default phpunit-methods is also perfect covered after merging... it seems only code that is covered by browser-kit-testing is not clearly defined in .cov-file ?!

Anyone that has the same problem (or better: a solution) ?